# UIWebView: how do I start from a blank view each time?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I'm looking up web pages using `UIWebView` and `NSURLRequest` and it's working fine, but I want it to start with a blank page each time, rather than displaying the results of the last URL lookup.  Is there an easy way to do that?

I'm doing this in `viewDidLoad:`

```
wikiText = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370)] autorelease];
[wikiView addSubview:wikiText];
```

...and then I load the `UIWebView` like this:

```
NSString *urlAddress =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@", randomEWiki];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]; 

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[wikiText loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this first.

```
 [wikiText loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]]];
```

This loads a blank page first. then open your usual URL.

```
 NSString *urlAddress =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@", randomEWiki];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]; 

 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [wikiText loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: I would recommend using the 'about:blank' URL, as its somewhat standard and should give a proper blank screen.

Comment: this too would give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Html tags like this

```
[wikiText loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

Then after you can load your actual url

```
NSString *urlAddress =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@", randomEWiki];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]; 

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[wikiText loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to load load blank URL, you just use `viewWillAppear`, according to this, every time when your view will appear then `webView` will load your page and initially gives you white blank page then your url page.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    wikiText = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370)] autorelease];
    [wikiView addSubview:wikiText];


    NSString *urlAddress =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@", randomEWiki];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]; 
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [wikiText loadRequest:requestObj]; 
}
```